# Trying to identify this bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Not sure if it was a good purchase? I have looked around the internet trying to find a similar badge but no luck. Here is a pic.  Thanks for looking.

[image: Matte black bicycle with raised handlebars and flat pedals. No cables are evident, so it may be a fixie but the rear hub is obscured.]

Comment: I know you're trying to ID the brand, but unless you're a collector, "good purchase" is really determined by you - is it in good condition? Will it meet your needs? Was it a price you considered reasonable? Then it was a good purchase!

Comment: @FreeMan concur - its a good purchase if the owner wants to ride it.

Comment: You will likely get the best answer if you post  a nice clear picture of just the headbadge.

Comment: Take a head-on close-up picture of the emblem and drop it into Google image search.